# Why __unicode__ doesn't work but __str__ does?

Tags: django, string, python-3.x, django-models, unicode

I'm trying to break some rock by developing a website on my own, and I'm starting by creating some registry pages and listing database records.

I'm getting bugged with the fact that `__unicode__` method doesn't print the username of my records and `__str__` does!

I know that using `__unicode__` is the best practice to have, but I can only print my object username with `__str__`.

Can anybody explain why this happens?

My Model:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    reg_date = models.DateTimeField('registry date')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

My admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from registo.models import User

admin.site.register(User)
```

My `__unicode__(self)` output:

```
User
    User object
```

My `__str__(self)` output:

```
User
    Teste
```

Thanks for your cooperation in advance!

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: Hello Sudipta! Thanks for your quick answer! :).

I'm using 1.5.1 version! 

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

it looks like you are using `Python3.x` and here is the [relevant documentation on `Str and Unicode methods`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods)

> In Python 2, the object model specifies `__str__()` and `__unicode__()`
>   methods. If these methods exist, they must return str (bytes) and
>   unicode (text) respectively.
>
> The print statement and the str() built-in call `__str__()` to determine
>   the human-readable representation of an object. The unicode() built-in
>   calls `__unicode__()` if it exists, and otherwise falls back to
>   `__str__()` and decodes the result with the system encoding. Conversely, the Model base class automatically derives `__str__()` from
>   `__unicode__()` by encoding to UTF-8.
>
> In Python 3, there’s simply `__str__()`, which must return str (text).

So

> On Python 3, the decorator is a no-op. On Python 2, it defines
>   appropriate `__unicode__()` and `__str__()` methods (replacing the
>   original `__str__()` method in the process).

Comment: Hello Karthikr! Thanks for your quick answer! :).

So, since in python 3 there is simply __str__, i must only use this to print what i want from objects, from now on, is that right?

Thanks for pasting here the documentation also! :)

Comment: That is correct. If you want compatibility, you can look into [python_2_unicode_compatible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible) decorator

Comment: Ok. I Appreciate your help!

Since it's a version "problem", i'm kinda relieved because it's not my problem :).

Thanks for your help once again! :)

Answer (score 2):

If it's not the python 3 thing, your code as posted has incorrect indentation - not sure if copy/pasting bug or if that's how it is in the code. But your `User` model's methods need to be indented, like so:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    reg_date = models.DateTimeField('registry date')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: Wouldn't referencing `self` outside a class throw an exception?

Comment: If the function were called, sure. But as shown, the function is just defined at the module level, and that code path would never get called.

Comment: Hello Adam! Thanks for your quick answer.

So...i'm using pyCharm, and i guess the identation is correct! I'm avoiding copy-paste in order to learn more, but i tried with your code + identation, but the result was the same! :/.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Yeah, meant copy/paste into the SO question. Can you show a python shell session that shows how you're getting your `__str__` and `__unicode__` output - iow, `u= User.objects.get()`, `print repr(u.__unicode__())`, `print repr(u.__str__())`?

Comment: I'm guessing that is the Python 3.0 "thing" :) that is bugging my aaplication Adam :S.

About the shell session, i input those commands but `print repr` is showing as "invalid syntax"

:)

Comment: @Sammy yeah, nevermind, the issue is the python 3 thing. karthikr's answer i the one you want.

Comment: try `print(repr)` as `print` if a function in `python3.x`

Comment: Very well. 

I appreciate your help as well! :).Thank you. Hope to discuss in the future again :D.