# Cannot get model objects to display attributes in the django admin pages

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My models.py :

```
class Departement(models.Model):
    departNumber = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, primary_key= True)
    departName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.departNumber
```

My admin.py:

```
class DepartementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('departNumber', 'departName')

admin.site.register(Departement, DepartementAdmin)
```

The problem is, I cannot get any "Departement" object. I have tried .get(), .filter() or .all(). In both cases, it returns and does not print the department number.

```
<Departement: Departement object>
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Edit: To be more specific, in the database, I have a table "Departement" containing department names and numbers. For example if I type:

```
Departement.objects.filter(departNumber=2)
```

It should give me a departName that is "Var" since "Var" is the department with 2 as a primary key.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You *have* got a Department object.

Comment: Well, this *is* a `Department` object...

Comment: move your def __unicode__(self):
    return self.departNumber within the class. that's why its not printing department no.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: I've updated my answer now you have added more information to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `__unicode__` to `__str__` method and see. It should work with python 3.

```
class Departement(models.Model):
    departNumber = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, primary_key= True)
    departName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.departNumber
```

to make it compatible with python 2 you can do what's suggested here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> `Departement.objects.filter(departNumber=2)` should give me a departName
>   that is "Var" since "Var" is the department with 2 as a primary key.

So you are relying on the `__unicode__` method to return the department name (even though your implementation of the `__unicode__` method currently returns the department number).

Why not access the attribute directly?

```
dept = Departement.objects.filter(departNumber=2)
dept.departName
```

It makes for more maintainable code in the long run.

But to answer the *why* it's not working we need to know if you are using python 2 or 3.

If 3 then change the name of the method to `__str__` as described here: [Why `__unicode__`doesn't work but `__str__` does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189874/why-unicode-doesnt-work-but-str-does)

Comment: I am using python 3. `dept = Departement.objects.filter(departNumber=2)` `dept.departName` gives an Error. @Tony